# Not able to scroll an element on click using useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

Code:

```
const scrollRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const onClickScroll = (scrollOffset: number) => {
  scrollRef!.current!.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
};
```

Component:

```
<span className="flex">
 <ChevronLeftIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white cursor-pointer" onClick={()=> onClickScroll(-20)}/>
 <ChevronRightIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white cursor-pointer" onClick={() => onClickScroll(20)}/>
</span>
```

Scrollable component:

```
<div className="flex mt-5 w-[80rem] overflow-scroll overflow-y-clip scrollbar-hide" ref={scrollRef}>Somecode</div>
```

`onClickScroll` should trigger a scroll but doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) method, instead of trying to mutate the property. Try doing so:

```
const onClickScroll = (scrollOffset: number) => {
  scrollRef!.current!.scrollTo(scrollOffset, 0);
};
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: See this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-tamas-1uik9m?file=/src/App.js) I created. It's working. I assume you didn't add the `scrollRef` on the relevant element. See the CSS there as well.

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, is your problem solved or still not?